# Avoid loading a script in Woocommerce thank you page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

IN Woocommerce, I use **Header & Footer plugin** to add on body tag a tracking affiliate code for the whole site.

The code is:

```html
<script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script>
<script>
window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};lw.l=+new Date;
lw("setProgram", "12838");
lw("setDecimal", ".");
</script>
```

My affiliate partner ask me the code be disabled from woocommerce thank you page (according the image - Line935 to 940).

woocommerce thank you page source code:

[image: woocommerce thank you page source code]

I think I need to add_filter action or something to disable it.

Any help will be useful for this.

**UPDATE:** If I remove the code from Header & Footer plugin is disabled from the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a plugin, use the following to avoid your script to be loaded on thankyou page.

You have 2 choices:

1) On Footer *(the best choice, I think)*:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'linkwi_delivery_script' );
function linkwi_delivery_script(){
    // Not on thankyou page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return;
    ?>
    <script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};lw.l=+new Date;
    lw("setProgram", "12838");
    lw("setDecimal", ".");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

2) On Header:

```
add_action( 'wp_head' , 'linkwi_delivery_script' );
function linkwi_delivery_script(){
    // Not on thankyou page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return;
    ?>
    <script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};lw.l=+new Date;
    lw("setProgram", "12838");
    lw("setDecimal", ".");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Perfect my friend!!! It works. I remove the script from Header & Footer plugin and i add your code in funcrion.php of my child theme.

Answer (score 1):

So finaly my code in child function.php it look like this.

```html
// Utility function that contain Linkwise Affiliate script
function linkwise_affiliate_scripts( $order_id ){

    ## --- YOUR SETTINGS START BELOW --- ##

    $program_id  = '12838'; // <== Your program number
    $decimal_sep = '.';     // Decimal separator
    $currency    = '978';   // For "EUR" => See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

    ## --- END SETTINGS --- ##

    $order        = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    $items_string = array();
    $count        = 0;

    ?>
    <script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tlwt.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};
    lw .l=+new Date;
    lw("setProgram", "<?php echo $program_id; ?>");
    lw("setDecimal", "<?php echo $decimal_sep; ?>");
    </script>
    <script>

        lw("setCurrency", "<?php echo $currency; ?>"); // Set your currency
        <?php
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ):
                $count++;
                $item_id        = $item->get_id(); // The item ID

                // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
                $product        = $item->get_product();
                $product_id     = $item->get_product_id(); // Product ID
                $price_excl_vat = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // Unit price excluding VAT
                $item_qty       = $item->get_quantity(); // Item quantity
                $payout         = '1'; // (???)

                // The string for the <noscript> at the bottom
                $items_string[] = "itemid[$count]=$item_id&amp;itemprice[$count]=$price_excl_vat&amp;itemquantity[$count]=$item_qty&a
        mp;itempayout[$count]=$payout";

        ?>
        lw("addItem", {
            id: "<?php echo $item_id; // Or can be the product ID (may be) ?>"
            ,price: "<?php echo $price_excl_vat; ?>"
            ,quantity: "<?php echo $item_qty; ?>"
            ,payout: "<?php echo $payout; ?>"
        });
        <?php
            endforeach;

            // Set the array of items strings in a unique string
            $items_string = implode( '&amp;', $items_string );
        ?>
        // Other items types
        <?php
            $coupon_discounts = $coupon_discounts_tax = 0;
            foreach( $order->get_items('coupon') as $item_coupon ){
                $coupon_discounts     += $item_coupon->get_discount();
                $coupon_discounts_tax += $item_coupon->get_discount_tax();
            }
        ?>
        lw("setCoupon", "<?php echo $coupon_discounts; ?>");
        lw("thankyou", {
            orderid: "<?php echo $order_id; ?>"
            ,status: "<?php echo $order_status; ?>"
        });
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img
        src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/acl.php?program=<?php echo $program_id; ?>&amp;decimal=<?php echo $decimal_sep; ?>&amp;<?php echo $items_string; ?>&amp;coupon_price=<?php echo $coupon_discounts; ?>&amp;status=<?php echo $order_status; ?>&amp;orderid=<?php echo $order_id; ?>" style="width:0px;height:0px;"/>
    </noscript>
    <?php echo 'test';
}

add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'wc_linkwise_affiliate_order_received_integration' );
function wc_linkwise_affiliate_order_received_integration() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) )
        return; // Exit

    global $wp;

    $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
    if ( empty($order_id) || $order_id == 0 )
        return; // Exit

    linkwise_affiliate_scripts( $order_id ); // Run the Linkwise Affiliate
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'linkwi_delivery_script' );
function linkwi_delivery_script(){
    // Not on thankyou page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) return;
    ?>
    <script async src="//go.linkwi.se/delivery/js/tl.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.lw=window.lw||function(){(lw.q=lw.q||[]).push(arguments)};lw.l=+new Date;
    lw("setProgram", "12838");
    lw("setDecimal", ".");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```